# MySQL view - calculated column from multiple tables returning NULL

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, calculated-columns, sql-view

Suppose I have a two tables. Table `T1` like:

```
Game Player Points Assists
 1     1     10     5
 1     2     5      10
```

`T2` like:

```
Game Player Fouls Turnovers
1      1     5       5
1      2     10      10
```

I'd like to create a view with one row per player and a new field `rating`, where `rating` is a equally weighted sum of `Points, Assists, Fouls,Turnovers` for each player. (i.e. rating = .25 * Points + .25 * Assists + .25 * Fouls + .25 * Turnovers)

I create the view:

```
CREATE VIEW `player_view` AS (
SELECT Player,
  SUM( 
  Points *0.25 +
  Assists *0.25 +
  Fouls *0.25 +
  Turnovers *0.25) AS Rating)
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON
  T1.Player = T2.Player
AND T1.Game = T2.Game
GROUP BY Player
```

But rather than returning a value, I get `NULL` for all `Rating`:

```
Player Rating
1       NULL
2       NULL
```

Initially, I was faced with

`Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'support_desk.mod_users_groups.group_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

So I disabled `only_full_group_by` via `SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'`

So now, although the view returns a results set, the `Ratings` are all NULL. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you missed  an operator between the column in  sum  eg + 
could be you ahve some hidden char in the key fields so.. try trim()

```
CREATE VIEW `player_view` AS 
SELECT Player,
  SUM( 
  t1.Points*0.25 + 
  t1.Assists*0.25  +
  t2.Fouls*0.25 + 
  t2.Turnovers*0.25) AS Rating
  )
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON
  trim(T1.Player) = trim(T2.Player)
    AND trim(T1.Game) = trim(T2.Game);
GROUP BY Player

select * from player_view;
```

Comment: you're right, I wrote the example in haste. My real query w/ real tables has the operators. I will correct it in the first post.

Comment: answer  update using trim  .. and you shout restore the full group by clause